# XML Path expression

Tags: for-xml-path

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>telnet</groupId>
          <artifactId>telnet.service</artifactId>
          <version>1.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xmlthing</groupId>
          <artifactId>xmlthing.service</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>parser</groupId>
          <artifactId>parser.service</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

How to be more substantive than this?
I have problem extracting value from the `version` attribute where `groupId=telnet`. How can I get xmlpath value of `1.10.0-SNAPSHOT` where `groupId=telnet`?

Sorry not for mention it before:
It should be in linux/unix format (xmllint, grep, sed ...) anything :)
Thanks a lot!
Brgds,
S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with selecting all `version` elements nested in `dependency` elements:

```
//pom:dependency/pom:version
```

and then qualify the `dependency` appropriately:

```
//pom:dependency[pom:groupId = 'telnet']/pom:version
```

Of course, you need to specify the namespaces for XPath as well.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $x | Select-Xml '//pom:dependency[pom:groupId = ''telnet'']/pom:version' -Namespace @{pom = 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'} | % node


#text
-----
1.10.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution using xpath:

```
xpath -q -e "//dependency[groupId='telnet']/version/text()" pom.xml
```